# Is there a way to get a list of the R objects in a file you're using load() on? If so, is it possible to load them individually?

Tags: r, internals

Trying to load() a file that ends up giving me an error:

```
load('.RDataTmp', verbose = T)

Loading objects:
  object1
  object2
  object3
  object4
  object5
Error in load(".RDataTmp", verbose = T) : error reading from connection
```

when I try to load it. Obviously, I messed up the name when I was saving this originally, but just when messing around I was able to save and load other objects with similarly messed up names. But it's appearing to load some of the objects before failing at loading some later object (secondary question, does this mean it loaded object5 successfully, or that's where the error occurred?). Is there a way to get a list of all the objects in the file? Then, is there a way to try and load only some of the objects?

Comment: Does `object5` *look* normal? I don't know how to trigger this failure, so I don't have a way to test it atm, sorry.

Comment: I cannot be certain, because I don't know for certain what's saved there. I did, however, save something with the same name as ```object5``` and it looks fine. I'm not looking for a way to avoid this error specifically. Just looking for a way to see what objects are in a file without load()-ing the file and wondering if there's a way to then load the "good" object individually without loading the "bad" ones.

Comment: ```attach('.RDataTmp')``` causes the same error - ```Error in load(what, envir = as.environment(pos)) : 
  error reading from connection```